# Add to list vs. Increment

Tags: python

Given that in Python:

```
element = element + [0]
```

should be equal to:

```
element += [0]
```

Why does one modify a list and the other does not? Here is a example:

```
>>> a = [[0, 0], [0,0]]
>>> for element in a:
...     element = element + [0]
... 
>>> a
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

a is not modified. But if I increment:

```
>>> a = [[0, 0], [0,0]]
>>> for element in a:
...     element += [0]
...
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

a is modified.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 7):

This is a fun side-effect of `+=` operatior, which calls `__iadd__` instead of `__add__`.

The statement `x = x + y` is equivalent to `x = x.__add__(y)`, while `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`.

This lets the `list` class optimize `+=` by extending the existing (ex, `x += y` is roughly equivalent to `x.extend(y)`) list instead of creating an entirely new list (which is what `+` needs to do).

For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> original_a = a
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> original_b = b
>>> a += [4]
>>> b = b + [4]
>>> a is original_a
True
>>> b is original_b
False
```

You can see that using `+=` maintains the identity of the left hand side (ie, a new list *isn't* created) while using `+` does *not* maintain the identity (ie, a new list *is* created).

For more, see: http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.iadd and the paragraph directly above the documentation for `operator.iadd`.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, element = element + [0], you are creating a new list.

In the second case, element += [0], you are modifying an existing list.

Since the list of lists, a, contains pointers to the elements, only modifying the elements will actually change things. (That is, creating a new list does not change the pointers in a.)

This is seen more clearly if we take a simple example showing how lists work:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[4, 5, 6]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a += [4, 5, 6]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Assigning a variable to a list simply assigns a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what others said, there is a difference in what these statements do:

```
element = element + [0]
```

does

```
element = element.__add__([0])
```

while

```
element += [0]
```

does

```
element = element.__iadd__([0])
```

`__iadd__()`, in this case, is free to determine what to return: the original object with a modification or a new object.

In the case of a immutable object, it must return a different one (e.g., `a = b = 8; a += 9` => `a is not b`.

But in the case of a mutable object, such as a list, it normally modifies this one:

```
a = b = []
a += [8]
```

=> `a is b`.

This different behaviour reflects in your for loop:

```
for element in a:
   element = element + [0]
```

=> name `element` gets rebound to a different object; original one remains untouched

```
for element in a:
   element += [0]
```

=> original object, which is as well contained in the outer list, `a`, gets modified. The fact that `element` is reassigned is irrelevant; it is not used.